# How can you get a new answer to an old question without spending bounty?

Tags: discussion

I accidentally managed to ask a duplicate question earlier today as I didn't find the duplicate. However [the older question has no useful answers](https://superuser.com/questions/549381/windows-8-hides-cursor-when-mouse-is-unplugged) and I don't have enough rep to place a bounty and there's nothing to add by editing the question.

How can you get another answer to an old question without spending rep? It seems like a flaw in the system.

Comment: according to the Q, the problem is it goes into touch mode?  sharemouse indicates with tablets a mouse staying connected would fix this. http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/faq.htm   So if win8 is going into tablet mode, and the mouse driver for the KVM software is not faking a mouse (which is possible), try keeping a real mouse working on the win8 computer?  If that works, answer the question :-)

Comment: Upvoting bumps it to the front page. It's not guaranteed to yield an answer, but it helps

Comment: @allquixotic upvoting does not bump.

Comment: Earn rep by helping others.

Comment: There is a bounty reason which basically amounts to "I want this question to get more attention" the bounty system clearly isn't flawed for that reason.  If you want to issue a bounty, gets some reputation, by posting answers to other questions.

Comment: Correct version of @allquixotic's comment: "**Editing** bumps it to the front page. It's not guaranteed to yield an answer, but it helps"

Comment: Speaking of which, the Community randomly "pokes" (bumps) two "unanswered" questions (without any uprooted or accepted answer) every hour, so this helps clear out the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The system is set up so that you are forced to work for the site before you can get answers from the site.